# Enable and use HTML5 geolocation in WebView XCode (Cocoa)

Tags: html, cocoa, webview, webkit, geolocation

I'm trying to build a Mac OS X application with HTML5 content, and I would like to use the HTML5 geolocation feature in WebView.

For my test I use this basic demo page : http://html5demos.com/geo 
On Chrome or Safari, this page is working and the browser shows me an alert about location sharing (Chrome alert infos : https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142065).

In my application (a simple WebView in a window) the attempt of geolocate goes directly to fail.
 Here is a (not necessary) screenshot : http://i46.tinypic.com/fedqtw.png

So, I don't know exactly how to do it but maybe there is a way to intercept the attempt of geolocate and use a modal YesNo alert box to notice user...

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Beny

**PS:** I looked in `WebPreferencesPrivate` if possibly a native option to enable may exists, but no.

Comment: I have the same issue here, on android it works fine but on xcode/iphone it won't work yet. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution found for the moment... :s